# Изменение цвета объекта на изображении

Tags: javascript, css

Например у меня есть изображение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо сделать так чтобы я со своей палитры мог изменить цвет кухонного гарнитура и при этом не меняя цвет всего изображения.
Как и с помощью чего это можно реализовать?

Comment: Как вариант - вытащить из фотошопа, потом изменить hue.

Comment: Можно `canvas-ОМ`, можно `SVG` попробовать реализовать... А можно просто несколько картинок, как выше предлагалось и менять их  при выборе цвета

Answer (score 8):

Как отправная точка, для вдохновения и, просто, чтобы ответы не пустые были:

```css
img, input {
  position: absolute;
}
.color {
  z-index: 1;
  --module-color: 0deg;
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(var(--module-color));
  filter: hue-rotate(var(--module-color));
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(314px 24px, 330px 24px, 329px 147px, 326px 129px, 315px 132px, 303px 130px, 300px 161px, 301px 164px, 302px 169px, 299px 169px, 299px 167px, 295px 166px, 291px 151px, 289px 137px, 284px 139px, 273px 139px, 268px 137px, 269px 141px, 272px 164px, 89px 177px, 89px 187px, 83px 188px, 83px 124px, 279px 119px, 300px 121px, 300px 86px, 261px 86px, 261px 116px, 258px 116px, 258px 86px, 84px 83px, 84px 62px, 83px 58px, 81px 55px, 80px 53px, 74px 53px, 74px 28px, 80px 24px, 200px 33px, 200px 37px, 194px 40px, 156px 37px, 155px 56px, 200px 56px, 200px 62px, 156px 61px, 156px 81px, 200px 81px, 199px 83px, 248px 84px, 301px 82px, 330px 82px, 330px 54px, 289px 59px, 268px 59px, 268px 34px, 311px 25px);
  clip-path: polygon(314px 24px, 330px 24px, 329px 147px, 326px 129px, 315px 132px, 303px 130px, 300px 161px, 301px 164px, 302px 169px, 299px 169px, 299px 167px, 295px 166px, 291px 151px, 289px 137px, 284px 139px, 273px 139px, 268px 137px, 269px 141px, 272px 164px, 89px 177px, 89px 187px, 83px 188px, 83px 124px, 279px 119px, 300px 121px, 300px 86px, 261px 86px, 261px 116px, 258px 116px, 258px 86px, 84px 83px, 84px 62px, 83px 58px, 81px 55px, 80px 53px, 74px 53px, 74px 28px, 80px 24px, 200px 33px, 200px 37px, 194px 40px, 156px 37px, 155px 56px, 200px 56px, 200px 62px, 156px 61px, 156px 81px, 200px 81px, 199px 83px, 248px 84px, 301px 82px, 330px 82px, 330px 54px, 289px 59px, 268px 59px, 268px 34px, 311px 25px);
}
input[type="range"] {
  width: 395px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<img class="color" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvE4w.jpg"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvE4w.jpg">
<input type="range" min="0" max="360" oninput="document.querySelector('img').style.setProperty('--module-color', this.value + 'deg');" value="0">
```

Comment: А как/чем рассчитывался polygon?

Comment: @Nsk онлайн-сервисом. Их не так уж и много: для примитивов - https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ ; для фигур посложнее - http://www.cssplant.com/clip-path-generator . Конкретно в примере - вторым сервисом.

Comment: сложновато ручками через такой сервис. Может есть такой сервис/скрипты который построит полигон из готовой маски (например подготовленой в фотошопе) типа этой https://configurator.fierashop.ru/confimages/l/1/4/79.png

Comment: @Nsk есть сервисы для конвертации вектора в SVG (почти clip-path). Т.е. в редакторе сохраняем маску и загоняем в сервис. Правда, кривые эти сервисы, просто жуть - достаточно того, что нельзя масштабировать и преобразовать туда-обратно абсолютные координаты в относительные.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно несколько фото – одно со статичным фоном, а другое с прозрачным фоном и мебелью. Именно цвет второго фото 
вы сможете регулировать, к примеру, через

`filter: hue-rotate(90deg);`

Comment: Мне нужно что то вроде этого https://configurator.fierashop.ru/l?k=10137050707

Comment: Интересно посмотреть как функцией `hue-rotate()` нужные цвета подберешь...  Мне это кажется неоптимальным.

Comment: @Alex.G в примере по ссылке тупо загружается "маска" картинкой https://configurator.fierashop.ru/confimages/l/1/4/79.png, реализовать программно практически не реально - потыкай пипеткой на кухню из своего вопроса, на ней будет 3-4-5 и более цветов (тени, блики и прочее). Даже ручками и фотошопом не всегда подобное быстро и ровно вырезается, а ты тут web-скриптами хочешь.

Comment: @Air смотри ответ UModeL.

Comment: Разобрался. Сафари не всю папку с картинками показал.

Comment: @MobiDevices, видел ответ...  Такую задачу, данным методом не решают...  )))

Comment: @Air напишите ваш ответ, как правильно решить. Будет интересно увидеть ещё мнения. К сожалению, здесь уже не получится, но можете сделать на codepen.

Comment: Я ответ писать не буду, так как с `canvas` не дружу на таком уровне. Но знаю, что такие задачи просто `css функцией hue-rotate()`  не решить. Да в ответе есть некое подобие имитации желания автора вопроса. Но оно не полноценно.  И очень скудно на мой взгляд...