# Изменить определенные детали не меняя всей картинки

Tags: изображения, реализация

Есть картинка машины, по идее нужно сделать так чтобы при клике на кнопки менялись или цвет или обвес или колеса.
Сказано сделать так, чтобы при каждом выборе не подгружалась новая картинка, а лишь выбранная ее часть. Т.е. если пользователь кликнет на кнопку "изменить цвет", то изменится цвет, если кликнет на "изменить обвес", то изменится обвес.

В моей реализации: я просто подгружаю новую картинку, а ведь если при каждом изменении подгружать новую картинку, то не будут доступны комбинации, как например, изменить и обвес и колеса, поскольку я каждый раз подгружаю тупо новую картинку. Я думал как это реализовать, но ничего не приходит в голову, может вы сталкивалась с таким или знаете как такое сделать, подскажите

*P.S. код не оставляю так как там просто смена картинки при клике на кнопочку*
*P.S.S. Я наверное не совсем понятно объяснил, отпишите в комментарии непонятные моменты пожалуйста*

Comment: комбинируйте картинку из нескольких изображений. будут у вас слои с кузовом, колесами, обвесом. их и меняйте

Comment: @teran неужели нельзя сделать такое без подгрузки целой новой картинки

Comment: цвет можно частично пробовать менять css фильтрами. обвесы придется грузить отдельно

Comment: @teran если пользоваться фильтрами, то фильтр разве не будет накладываться на всю картинку?

Comment: я вам выше описал подход с композицией из нескольких картинок. часть из них можно перекрашивать фильтрами.

Comment: @MidNightElf: **teran** дело говорит. Вот, может натолкнёт на мысль - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/906898/265406